# Two property changes in the same animation block have different durations. Why?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, ios

In the following `UIView` animation block, I do a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` and a `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`, and though the `duration` is set to `1.0f,` the scale goes really fast and the rotation goes in 1 second like it should.

It must be my lack of understanding about how `AffineTransforms` are applied but I can't figure it out.

What gives?

EDIT: Vladimir's answer worked great.  I was changing the same property twice, rather than changing two properties.  To make two changes to a `transform` property, you have to make a `transform` with the initial change, then add the second change to that `transform` and then set you object's `transform` from there.  This way, you can chain as many together as you want.

---

```
CGColorRef color = [[colorArray objectAtIndex:colorIndex] CGColor];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[[self layer] setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)];
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4)];
[[self layer] setBackgroundColor:color];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)];
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4)];
```

2nd line overrides the effect of 1st line. You should construct the whole transform and then apply it to your view:

```
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f,2.0f);
tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, M_PI/4);
[self setTransform: tr];
```